# Get keyboard height in Lollipop

Tags: android, keyboard, height, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

What did change in Lollipop about keyboard height?

I had a method which using `getViewTreeObserver()` correctly returned the height of the keyboard on every version before Lollipop (tested on ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi - no problems) but it seems that on Lollipop the height returned is a little bit larger that the real keyboard's height.

On my Asus Nexus 7 I got a height with about 70 px larger than the actual height.

Does anybody know how to get the real keyboard's height on Lollipop?

Comment: Ditto for Nexus 5 and Moto G running Lollipop. Any solutions so far?

Answer (score 3):

Try This Following Code When the Keyboard Opens Up.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public int calculateScreenHeightForLollipop() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size.y;
}

/**
 * Call this function to resize the emoji popup according to your soft keyboard size
 */
public void setSizeForSoftKeyboard() {
    rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int screenHeight;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 5.0) {
                screenHeight = calculateScreenHeightForLollipop();
            } else {
                screenHeight = rootView.getRootView().getHeight();
            }
            int heightDifference = screenHeight
                    - (r.bottom - r.top);
            int resourceId = mContext.getResources()
                    .getIdentifier("status_bar_height",
                            "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                heightDifference -= mContext.getResources()
                        .getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
            if (heightDifference > 100) {
                keyBoardHeight = heightDifference;
                setSize(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, keyBoardHeight);
                if (!isOpened) {
                    if (onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener != null)
                        onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener.onKeyboardOpen(keyBoardHeight);
                }
                isOpened = true;
                if (pendingOpen) {
                    showAtBottom();
                    pendingOpen = false;
                }
            } else {
                isOpened = false;
                if (onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener != null)
                    onSoftKeyboardOpenCloseListener.onKeyboardClose();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think it should be: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) right?

Comment: @FrankNguyen Yup it should be if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)